# Solving java classpath hell in legacy junit test suite

Tags: java, junit, dependencies, classpath

Suppose I have a legacy JUnit test suite that includes the following tests:

```
public class AwesomeTest {
     public void testBusinessLogic() {
     ...
     [awesome mocking library]
     ...
     }
}

public class AmazingTest {
    public void testBusinessProcess() {
    ...
    [amazing xml operation]
    ...
    }
}
```

Now assume that Awesome Mocking library relies on Awesome BCEL bytecode generation library which contains the class `org.useful.XMLClass` and this library has version 1 of XMLClass.

Now assume that Amazing Xml operation relies on Amazing Xml Library that contains the class `org.useful.XMLClass` and this library has version 2 of XML Class.

Also assume that version 2 of the class is not backwards compatible with version 1 - so which ever version has higher priority in the classpath - it breaks the dependencies of the other version.

Also assume that there are 400 tests that rely on awesome mocking library - so rewriting is not a desirable option.

Also assume that some critical business features have been built with amazing xml libary - and it is strongly preferred not to rewrite that.

How do you solve this classpath hell situation - apart from running the ant tests (assuming you're running them with Ant) twice with two differently manually ordered classpaths and manually determined test sub-sets? (I'm open to an idea with custom classloaders - but that seems about the same level of maintainability as the dual custom classpath with ant solution)

Comment: Yep, thats hell alright. The fault seems to be with the byte code generator that bundled the XML file in the first place. I would recommend updating your mocking library.

Comment: May be you could get the source code of the "Awesome BCEL bytecode generation library" and create a fork that rely on a renamed version of the class org.useful.XMLClass.

Comment: I agree there is no simple answer. You could try to use custom class loaders maybe ... but that just seems to be more effort than it's worth. I'd rewrite the tests using a new library for either the XML or mocking operations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I do believe a quite transparent solution is possible using a java agent and custom class loader. The idea is the following:

1. Use the [Instrumentation Framework](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/instrument/package-summary.html) (java agent) to intercept the classes when they are loaded. When you detect a class that is in the Awesome Mocking Library, replace all references to `org.useful.XMLClass` to, for example, `intercepted.org.useful.XMLClass`.
2. Create a custom class loader, in which you check if the requested class is `intercepted.org.useful.XMLClass`. If it is, load the version of `XMLClass` that is used by the Mocking Library. All other requests can be handled by default.

Use the custom class loader and attach the java agent when running the tests, and everything should run correctly, as if there is no dependency conflict.

Comment: That's pretty awesome. Is there a way to load up a copy version of the existing classpath and modify it at runtime - ie the same effect but without using an agent?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you mean by that, but without using an agent to differentiate the different versions of XMLClass, how would the runtime be able to decide which version to use from what point?

Answer (score 0):

I think Steven's answer is great - for the sake of completeness and because this question got so many votes - I wanted to share all the alternatives we thought of (including the bad ones)

1. Partition the tests (or some of the tests) out into a different classpath order 
   (disadvantage - could cause you to miss other important issues with your tests - not a viable option)
2. Roll back Amazing xml operation and implement another way (given the investment in the usage of this, and the fact that other operations had been exhausted - this was dismissed)
3. Rewrite the tests using a new mocking library (this is good in the long term - in the short term this works out to be bigger than our current project, because there are hundreds and hundreds)
4. Build a customised version of the amazing mocking library that uses the newer version of the `org.useful.XMLClass` (this turned out to be larger than our current project)
5. Extract out the offending class from source, and put the older version on the test classpath overriding the source library (it turned out this was entangled with several other classes - so this was non-trivial)
6. Use Steven's fantastic idea above - again this turned out to be non-trivial
7. Set the tests with @Ignore - and put them in the queue for rewriting on a future project.